# Can't get CSS drop down nav to go over content

Tags: css, html, nav

Ok, I have tried everything I can think of and can't get z-index:1; to put my drop down menu on top of the content and page title.  Can someone please take a look and tell me what I have wrong?

Thanks so much (in advance)

http://jsfiddle.net/kreali/cDgH2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `div.myMain` have `z-index:1000;` so your `#nav_home` must have bigger z-index! Put `z-index: 9999;` on `#nav_home`. Here is edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cDgH2/1/

Comment: Wow, 2 days I racked my brain on this.  Should have just came you guys!  Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/cDgH2/2/

You had the `z-index` on `div.myMain` set to 1000, which was higher than the `z-index: 1` on the `#nav_home`.