# Dropdown menu in css disappears on hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I keep getting a problem with my css - tried modifying the code many times but still stuck. Before I paste all the CSS (there is a lot), maybe someone knows what the problem could be from the GIF below.

Basically, when you hover over the language, the menu opens. When you move down to French/Russian the dropdown disappears.

I get the feeling it has something to do with hovering over the picture below.

Many thanks.

[image]

**EDITED**

Just found the answer here: [Can't get CSS drop down nav to go over content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764192/cant-get-css-drop-down-nav-to-go-over-content)

I had to set the z-index for the nav to 9999 in order to get bring it into highest priority.

Many thanks for your comments and answers.

~Aivoric

Comment: Save yourself a world of bother and use http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: Can't really tell from the GIF, post code , or even better a jsfiddle showing it in action

Comment: I think you would be better of creating a JS Fiddle

Comment: Probably because of the size of the picture.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qndamhx5/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="language-choice">
  <a href="#">ENGLISH <span class="red active"></span></a>
  <a href="#">GERMAN <span class="red"></span></a>
  <a href="#">FRENCH <span class="red"></span></a>
  <a href="#">RUSSIAN <span class="red"></span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.language-choice{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:  10px;
    border-radius:  10px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    border: green solid 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.language-choice:hover{
    height: 160px;
}
.language-choice a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: green;
}
.language-choice a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.language-choice a .red{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: red solid 2px;
}
.language-choice a:hover .red, .language-choice a .active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cheslab - just found the answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764192/cant-get-css-drop-down-nav-to-go-over-content

Comment: Had to set the z-index to 9999 :)

Comment: I don't know why so many people use such enormous z-index, as you can see the guy from question you've mentioned had a really headache because of value of z-index equal 1000. I think it would be better practice to use smaller values.